# Manipulating Basic Limit Laws of the Real or Complex Numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits

For these basic limit laws from elementary calculus:

If $\, \lim_{x \to a}f(x), \,  \lim_{x \to a}g(x)\,$ **EXIST** then

- $\lim_{x \to a} c\cdot f(x) = c \cdot \lim_{x \to a}f(x)\, ,c$ constant.
- $\lim_{x \to a}\{f(x) \pm g(x)\} = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \pm \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$
- $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$
- $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)} ,\,\, \lim_{x \to a}g(x) \neq 0$
- $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f \lim_{x \to a} g(x)\, $, provided $f$ is continuous at that $g$ limit.

Why do these need to be prefaced with *if the limits exist*? Wouldn't they *not exist* regardless of the use of these laws? In other words, I can't see how it would be possible to make a limit exist by ignoring the predefined condition that they do exist.

Comment: The point is that if the former limits do not exist, there is no any guarantee that the subsequent limits will exist. For instance, take $f(x) = g(x) = (-1)^n$, the limits $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ do not exist, and nor do the limits $\lim c\cdot f(x)$ and $\lim c\cdot g(x)$ for any non-zero $c$.

Comment: To add to this, it's possible to, for example, have two functions $f$ and $g$ so that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ do not exist but $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x)$ exists. If both sides of the equation make sense, then the two quantites will be equal. But in this case it doesn't make sense to say $(\lim_{x \to a} f(x)) \cdot (\lim_{x \to a} g(x))$!

Comment: Have you seen the proof of these laws? If yes,  then you will find that the existence of the limits is used in a particular manner. They can be generalized to some extent requiring the existence of only one of the limits (either for $f$ or $g$) but then the interpretation of the laws is somewhat different. See the last few paragraphs of this post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-2.html

Comment: Moreover the use of these laws is to get information about limit of complicated expression based on the information of limits of the simpler sub-expressions which make up that expression via combination using algebraic symbols $+, - \times, /$. To use these laws one must know the limits of simple expressions by other means (either via definition of limits or via some list of standard limits which are proved on case by case basis).  You can see such limits in the blog post I linked earlier.